# Basic Python module error

Tags: python, module

So I'm learning python, from a java background, for my new job, and I've run into the following error.

I tried running this module on the terminal (using mac), then through IDLE. All futile.

```
   userName = input("What is your name?: ")
   lengthName = str(len(usernName))

   yourName = "\nYour name is " + userName + " and is " + legnthName + " letters long."

   print(yourName)
   input("\nPress enter to exit")
```

When this is executed in the terminal and I type for the first input : "John" I get this as a result:

```
   File "[...]", line 1, in <module>
   userName = input("What is your name?: ")
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
   NameError: name 'John' is not defined
```

Similarly, when executed via IDLE:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/Users/zachmartin/Desktop/python fails/lol.py", line 2, in <module>
       lengthName = str(len(usernName))
   NameError: name 'usernName' is not defined
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems:

- You should be using `raw_input()` rather than `input()` (because `input()` will treat what you type as Python code and try to evaluate it).
- You have a typo, `userName` vs. `usernName` (note the extra `n`).  (Also `legnthName` later on.)